# How can I push arrays generated within for loops into an empty array outside the loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, push

(I know similar questions have been asked in the past but I can't find a satisfactory answer... sorry!)

Hi all,

I'm using a for-loop within a for-loop, resulting in new arrays.

Each time the inner loop runs, I'd like to push the resulting array into a pre-created empty array. I'm expecting an array of arrays.

When I test by console-logging each of the arrays generated within the inner loop, all the arrays I expect are being created. 
But, weirdly, when I try to .push() each one onto the pre-created empty array, I end up with an array full of index numbers, rather than an array of arrays (???) .

If anyone managed to follow that description, please help!! Thanks very much!

```js
const isColourful = num => {
  const arr = num.toString().split('');

  const blankArr = [];

  const arrayOfArraysMaker = arr => {
    for (let c = 0; c < arr.length; c++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i + c > 0) {
          x = i + c;
        } else {
          x = undefined;
        }

        const workingArr = blankArr.push(arr.slice(i, x));
        console.log(blankArr);
      }
    }
  };

  arrayOfArraysMaker(arr);

  return arr;
};

console.log(isColourful(2457));
```

Returns a list of numbers 1 through 16, when I was expecting an array of the following arrays:

```
[ '2', '4', '5', '7' ]
[]
[]
[]
[ '2' ]
[ '4' ]
[ '5' ]
[ '7' ]
[ '2', '4' ]
[ '4', '5' ]
[ '5', '7' ]
[ '7' ]
[ '2', '4', '5' ]
[ '4', '5', '7' ]
[ '5', '7' ]
[ '7' ]
```

Comment: Do you mean you intend to create an array containing all the possible combinations of a given string of numbers?

Comment: When I [run your code](https://jsbin.com/jeqifemebe/edit?js,console), I get your expected output

Comment: You're returning `arr`, did you mean to return `blankArr`?

Comment: "Returns a list of numbers 1 through 16" - it does not. It returns `const arr = num.toString().split('');`. The inner function only ever mutates `blankArr`, which is unused. The inner function doesn't return anything.

Comment: What is the `workingArr` variable for? You assign it, but never use it. Are you using it in the version that's returning the incorrect result?

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments, guys. Alex's answer below sorted me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, but I think I see what might have you confused.

```
const workingArr = blankArr.push(arr.slice(i, x));
```

This line doesn't do what you might be thinking.

Array's push method returns the new length of the array [(documentation here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

If you were using the returned value from `push` then you would get a number increasing by one everytime that `push()` is called on that array, since the array gets one item longer each time.

You shouldn't use the return value of `push()` at all here, as it modifies the original array.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, that's so helpful. 